# Create boolean array by testing elements of another array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, time, boolean

I have a column of time array type (i.e. `{06:00:00, 07:00:00, ...}`) and want to compare each element of this array to see if it is between a `from_time` and `to_time` column (e.g. 09:00:00 in from_time and 18:00:00 in to_time), and then generate a boolean array in a new column (e.g. `{True, False, ...}`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, t.time_arr, a.bool_arr
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT elem BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:00'
      FROM   unnest(t.time_arr) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, ord)
      ORDER  BY ord
      ) AS bool_arr
   ) a;
```

Requires Postgres 9.4.
[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1fc8/1) with a simpler version for Postgres 9.3

There was a very similar question on dba.SE just yesterday. Answer with more details:

- [Preserve order of array elements after join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119702/3684)